# How do I get the value of an object member that has a pipe?

Tags: php

Given this object, how do I output the value of `pipe|title?`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [profile|title] => John Doe
)
```

I've never seen a pipe in a member name before.

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the curly brackets and put the field name in a string:

```
$obj->{'profile|title'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I always forget about generic objects versus arrays.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
$obj->{'profile|title'}
```

Since you're just using it as a stupid data store, you can also cast it as an array

```
$arr = (array) $obj;
$arr['profile|title'];
```

This would be more useful if you're using a lot of values out of it this way or you need to iterate over it.